# Label on TextInputEditText missing on binding using mvvm cross Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-textinputedittext

I am implementing 2 TextInputEditText for username field and password field using Xamarin. I am using MVVM cross so basically I set the text and hint for TextInputEditText in the .cs file. My code is as below:

XAML layout:

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"

    android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColorHint="#BCB8BA"
        android:textColor="#110F10"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The binding stuff in cs file:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
set.Bind(etUsername)
   .For(v => v.Text)
   .To(vm => vm.UsernameTextField.Text);
set.Bind(etUsername)
   .For(v => v.Hint)
   .To(vm => vm.UsernameTextField.Placeholder);
set.Bind(etPassword)
   .For(v => v.Text)
   .To(vm => vm.PasswordTextField.Text);
set.Bind(etPassword)
   .For(v => v.Hint)
   .To(vm => vm.PasswordTextField.Placeholder);
```

For some reason only the hint texts are displayed. If user focus on the text, the hint supposed to floating up and be a label but it is missing.

Anyone knows what happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you call set.Apply() somewhere? Where do you set Binding Context?

Comment: yeah I did call it by the end of set.Bind()

Comment: How is the BindingContext set?